# Query completed with error

Tags: asp.net

Coming from this code:

```
select * from UserInfm;

select * from tblResetPasswordRequests;



Create table tblResetPasswordRequests
(
 Id UniqueIdentifier Primary key,

 UserName nchar(15) Foreign key references UserInfm (UserName) NOT NULL,

 ResetRequestDateTime DateTime NOT NULL

)
```

I found the following error..........

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 4

There is already an object named 'tblResetPasswordRequests' in the database.

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong: *"There is already an object named 'tblResetPasswordRequests' in the database"*. You are trying to create ta table that already exists in the DB.

Comment: As the error says, there is already a table with that name, presumably from the last time you ran the query. Use `drop tblResetPasswordRequests` to remove it.

Comment: Error says the table "tblResetPasswordRequests" is already exits in your database  so remove this table first and then try to recreate it or modify your changes in existing table.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a table with name `tblResetPasswordRequests` but this table name `tblResetPasswordRequests` already exist in your database. If you just want to `select` then highlight this query `select * from tblResetPasswordRequests;` and click execute and don't execute the following query again because table already created

```
Create table tblResetPasswordRequests
(
 Id UniqueIdentifier Primary key,

 UserName nchar(15) Foreign key references UserInfm (UserName) NOT NULL,

 ResetRequestDateTime DateTime NOT NULL

)
```